# Marking posts as favourite in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, ios-app

I would like to have the facility to mark a post as favourite in the iOS app. If this feature exists please show me how to access it; if not I would like to have this feature as it would save me going to the main site and looking up the post again to mark it as favourite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the `Asked` or `Edited` text next to the name of the person asking the question. You will get a dialog where you can hit `Favorite`.

In your question click at the `42 min ago` text:

[image]

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not very intuitive IMO. Far more easier (and user friendly) to have the same 'star' under the voting triangles as in the main site. Less screen tapping as well.

Comment: My version of the iOS App for iPhone 4, does not do this, it's a "hidden" box around the Asked area and below.  If you find a question with "Edited by AlongUserName", tapping or press and holding one the word "Edit.." just toggles the text and does not show the dialogue

Comment: @Arie: Please see above. Can you test this on iPhone 4 emulator? Or do you have one there?

Comment: @MichaelStoner: You are sure you tapped on those three dots?

Comment: Going from RHS, 3 Dots fine, the text up to the start of the date (Say Oct 9 at 15:07) fine, the text above the date (say 'AlongUserName') is fine, but the Edited by is outside of the hit area

Comment: can send a video if that's helpful

Comment: Okay. Maybe it is better to ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll do that.